# Last image stretches forever while zooming out

Tags: html, css, image, display

If I try to zoom out to the max, whatever the image I put in, if it's the last one then it's going to strech out forever while the others stay how they should be.
[[image: 1(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wywqs.jpg)]
[image]

This is on 25% zoom.

```
<div class="sh3-background" id="scroll3">
                <img src="sh3-background.jpg" alt="" class="shbg">
                <img src="sh3-logo.png" alt="" class="sh2logobg">
                <div class="shcontent">
                    <h3>Silent Hill 3 is a survival horror game developed by Team Silent and published by Konami in 2003. It is the third installment in the Silent Hill series and a direct sequel to the first Silent Hill game. The game follows Heather, a teenager who becomes entangled in the machinations of the town’s cult, which seeks to revive a malevolent deity. The game was critically successful and praised for its presentation, including the environments, graphics and audio, as well as the overall horror elements and themes that are continued from past installments.</h3>
                    <h1>PLATFORMS:</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>PLAYSTATION 2</li>
                    </ul>
                    <iframe width="220" height="115"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9s5t6R3aWwY">
                    </iframe>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="shf-background" id="scroll4">
                <img src="shf-background.png" alt="" class="shbg">
                <img src="shf-logo.png" alt="" class="sh2logobg">
                <div class="shcontent">
                    <h3>Silent Hill f is an upcoming survival horror game developed by NeoBards Entertainment and published by Konami. It is the ninth mainline game in the Silent Hill franchise and the first mainline title in the franchise in over a decade. Unlike previous games in the series, it is not being set in the titular town, but in 1960s rural Japan.</h3>
                    <h1>PLATFORMS:</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>PLAYSTATION 5</li>
                        <li>STEAM</li>
                    </ul>
                    <iframe width="220" height="115"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZqzK_nqDU9M">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is the used CSS

```
  .shbg {
    position: absolute;
    width:99%;
  }

    .shcontent{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:1.2em;
    margin-top:0.5em;
    color:white;
    font-family:system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 37px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}
```

I tried messing around with height but it didn't matter, it's always the last image that gets put in that's screwed and I don't understand how to stop it.